# braintree webhook success notification to database

Tags: php, braintree

Hello i'm new when it comes of coding, but i'm trying to engage my self to braintree/php sdk.

Now, I have an active braintree webhook url but I dunno how to fetch braintree subscription attributes/parameters, when subscription is success.

Other problem, I have implemented some codes that braintree gives me, but still I dunno if this is working or not.

I simple want to save customer details to my database when the subscription are successfully done.

Here is my webhook code.

```
public static function handleWebhook(){

  Braintree_Configuration::environment('sandbox');
  Braintree_Configuration::merchantId('my_id');
  Braintree_Configuration::publicKey('my_key');
  Braintree_Configuration::privateKey('my_private_key');

  if((Router::$aPost["bt_signature"]) && isset(Router::$aPost["bt_payload"])) {
    $webhookNotification = Braintree_WebhookNotification::parse(
      Router::$aPost["bt_signature"], 
      Router::$aPost["bt_payload"]
    );

    $message = "[Webhook Received " 
               . $webhookNotification->timestamp->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "] "
               . "Kind: " . $webhookNotification->kind . " | "
               . "Subscription: " . $webhookNotification->subscription->id . "\n";
  }
```

The whole code are only displaying the kind, but instead of doing that.
I want to get the whole customer detail when subscription successfully done.

thank you, hope somebody can help me.
Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact 
[support](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/forms/contact?_ga=2.66181102.1797210828.1526315761-1868041817.1513354075).</sub>

Braintree does not return the full customer object for a subscription webhook. In the Braintree API, subscriptions are tied to payment methods and not customers, however, you can certainly access the full customer object with the subscription object that is delivered with the webhook. Depending on the subscription, there are a couple of different ways.

1. If the subscription has associated transactions, you can access the [transactions array](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/response/subscription/php#transactions) within the subscription object, which you can then use to access the [customer details](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/response/transaction/php#customer_details) within that transaction object.

   `$webhookNotification->subscription->transactions[0]->customerDetails`
2. Pull the [payment method token](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/response/subscription/php#payment_method_token) string from the subscription and run a [customer search api call](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/customer/search/php#credit-card-fields), which will return the full customer object.

   ```
   $collection = $gateway->customer()->search([
       Braintree_CustomerSearch::cardholderName()->is("John Doe"),
       Braintree_CustomerSearch::paymentMethodToken()->is("the_payment_method_token")]);
   ```

Comment: thank you for your reply even if late :)
already found solution regarding on this matter, but thank you.